# Is there a function that returns a default value for a string that is not a valid number

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I would like to know if there is an nvl function for alphabetic characters, or I have to use a case in the select statement?

Ex :

```
EMPNO 
-----  
73A69
7369B
C7369
7369
736,9
73,69
73e,69
73,e69
```

I want to get this as a result:

```
0
0
0
7369
736,9
73,69
```

Comment: Try using isnumeric()

Comment: @DanielMarcus: there is no `isnumeric()` in Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my final solution

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(empno, '^[0-9]+([\,\.][0-9]+)?$') THEN 
        TO_NUMBER(empno) ELSE 0 END
      FROM   emp;
```

Comment: Hm, that looks like it will only work under certain conditions. How exactly do you want to treat `,` and `.` in your strings? Which is a thousand separator, which is the decimal separator?

Comment: I thought about it, but it is impossible for more than 90 to come out

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, but if your solution works for all your cases, it's fine. Usually when storing strings as numbers it would not be left to chance whether to use a comma or point. Which of '1.234' and '1,234' is 1234? That should be clearly defined.

Comment: if I have a number with decimal `ex 6.50 or 6,50` the other scripts do not read it and return `0`, which is wrong because I can have numbers with a comma

Comment: Still not clear, sorry. Are you saying that the numbers in the table never have thousand separators and that the decimal separator can both be a point or comma? So 6.500 and 6,500 would both be the same number, namely six and a half?

Comment: of course, in the table it is impossible for the number to be greater than 90.
this is why I can avoid managing the separators for the thousands.
at the same time a decimal number can have `.` or `,`.
I hope I have been as clear as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171678/discussion-between-giulio-angioli-and-thorsten-kettner).

Answer (score 3):

Oracle 12cR2 and above :

```
select TO_NUMBER ( EMPNO DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR ) FROM t;
```

Comment: Neato! Wasn't aware of this sugaring

Comment: if had i number with comma?

Comment: @GiulioAngioli : This still works if that is the case, but only if you are using  12cR2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're referring to this as `nvl`, but if you're just trying to convert a non-numeric string to `0`, I'd indeed use a `case`  expression with a `regexp_like` call:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(empno, '^[0-9]+$') THEN TO_NUMBER(empno) ELSE 0 END
FROM   emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a regular expression?

```
select (case when regexp_like(empno, '[^0-9,]' then 0 else empno end)
```

If you want to avoid `case`, you can play tricks, such as:

```
select coalesce(regexp_substr(empno, '^[0-9,]+$', 1, 1), '0')
```

But this is essentially the same logic.

Comment: if had i number with comma?

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that the numbers you find can contain a point or a comma and both represent the decimal separator. You've posted an answer yourself:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(empno, '^[0-9]+([\,\.][0-9]+)?$')
   THEN TO_NUMBER(empno) ELSE 0 END
FROM emp;
```

but that will fail on either the comma or the point, because the DBMS does not by default interprete both as a decimal separator.

You could of course simply select the string:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(empno, '^[0-9]+([\,\.][0-9]+)?$')
   THEN empno ELSE '0' END
FROM emp;
```

If you need to select the string converted to a number, make the string consistent (i.e. replace the point with a comma or vice versa) and display the appropriate format when using `TO_CHAR`:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(empno, '^[0-9]+([\,\.][0-9]+)?$') 
    THEN TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(empno, ',', '.'), '90.9999999') ELSE 0 END
FROM emp;
```

Accordingly, as of Oracle 12c Release 2 you could use:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE(empno, ',', '.') DEFAULT 0 ON CONVERSION ERROR, '90.9999999')
FROM emp;
```

(This latter query would, however, accept `'12,'` and `'12.'` as valid numbers (namely as the number 12), which your regular expression forbids.)